# Logo in center of nav

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm trying to make a nav with logo in the center using foundation.

So:

```
home | about | [LOGO] | services | work
```

Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uobaehLe/1/)

I want to keep all the nav stuff under the nav tag and the logo separate. I use push/pull classes to align it. The problem is, even though it's in the same row in the code, it's not working? Why?

Comment: You won't be able to push/pull elements wrapped in separate containers. They need to be siblings.

Comment: So how can I create a nav then with a logo in the center? Surley its not semantically correct to have the logo as part of the <nav> <ul>

Comment: @panthro, if you make it a link to your homepage it is

Comment: [Otherwise, this seems to work?](https://jsfiddle.net/peteng/uobaehLe/4/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply make the logo a list item and hide it from screen readers:

```
<li class="small-2 columns" aria-hidden="true">
    <img src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png" />
</li>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uobaehLe/2/)**

Or take Pete's advice and make it a home link.

```
<li class="small-2 columns"> 
    <a href="/">
        <img src="http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo32.png" />
    </a>
</li>
```